# How to make two mongodb queries atomic?

Tags: c#, mongodb, wcf, transactions, atomic

I am making two consecutive queries in order to update a 3 level deep array item(since the positional operator is not enough for objects deeper that 2 level; as known in [this feature request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831)) in `mongodb`.

Here are my queries:

```
#region Remove Folder

await new DbContext().Personnels.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(
        Builders<Personnel>.Filter.And(
            Builders<Personnel>.Filter.Eq("_id", PersonnelId),
            Builders<Personnel>.Filter.Eq("Devices._id", DeviceId)),
        Builders<Personnel>.Update.PullFilter("Devices.$.Folders",
        Builders<DeviceCloudFolder>.Filter.Eq("FolderId", FolderId)));

#endregion

#region Add Folder again

await new DbContext().Personnels.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(
        Builders<Personnel>.Filter.And(
            Builders<Personnel>.Filter.Eq("_id", PersonnelId),
            Builders<Personnel>.Filter.Eq("Devices._id", DeviceId)),
        Builders<Personnel>.Update.Push("Devices.$.Folders", folder));

#endregion
```

This way I can update the `folder` object but this will for sure cause some concurrency problems. This queries are made by `WCF` service(instance per request) methods. Since different calls to the service can call the methods at the same time they will be breaking the transaction.

I'm wondering if the standard [`lock mechanism`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) can work in "instance per request wcf proccesses"(I am guessing not)?

I've thought about generating file locks(open a file before making those 2 queries, close the file when the queries are over, and wait on a spinlock on that file for other simultaneous requests), but that didn't seem quite efficient.

I'm wondering what kind of workarounds exist?

Comment: You can read the document, update it in C# and overwrite the entire document if it still matches your search criteria.

Comment: Then there is the chance that I will wipe some other changes, and that is not unlikely.

Comment: You can add a last updated timestamp to your record and retry if the timestamp does not match the queried timestamp.Alternatively you should review your design.

Comment: Timestamp solution was in mind too, but does not work in this case.

Comment: Is a message queue (e.g. RabbitMQ) an option ? Updates can then just be queued with one process applying the updates in order.

Comment: Absolutely :) but I have zero idea about it.

Comment: Have a look at this page: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html